# A group action on another group action quotient: how to best describe the resulting structure and does it have a name?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory, group-actions, equivariant

Suppose I have an action $\alpha:G\times X\to X$ of a group $G$ on a set $X$ and, on top of that, an action $\beta:H\times(X/G)\to(X/G)$ of another group $H$ on the set of $G$-orbits.

Is there a nice way to turn this into a single group-action-like thing on $X$?

Maybe more rigorously: is there some group $\Xi(G,H)$ and an action of it on $X$, maybe with some additional data, which would enable me to reconstruct $G$, $H$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Does such $\Xi(G,H)$ have a name? Are its properties studied?

I made some moves but I am not sure if they are in right direction. From $\alpha$ and $\beta$ I can make (using axiom of choice) a map $\gamma:H\times X\to X$ and maps $\delta:X\to G$ and $\varepsilon:H\times H\times X\to G$ such that $\gamma(1,x)=\alpha(\delta(x),x)$ and $\gamma(h_1,\gamma(h_2,x))=\alpha(\varepsilon(h_1,h_2,x),\gamma(h_1h_2,x))$. Clearly one may write down appropriate identities, but all this looks like overkill.

**Later** I realized that one piece of data is missing: a map $\beta:H\times G\times X\to G$ satisfying $\gamma(h,\alpha(g,x))=\alpha(\beta(h,g,x),\gamma(h,x))$.

Comment: It's a bit of a torture to my brain to understand "is there some group ?(G,H)" not as "is there some group? $(G,H)$" along with a typo on spacing.

Comment: @YCor Is this better?

Comment: I'd have liked just another letter (an unknown in math is usually denoted by some random letter, not a question mark, especially since the question mark is also used in math sentences for its usual meaning) but at least it debugs a bit (even if "[?]" sounds like missing ref in a laTeX draft...). One criterion for a good notation would be something you could read to an audience.

Comment: @YCor To an audience I would tell "something(G,H)". But do you have a suggestion? Say, $\Xi(G,H)$?

Comment: $\Xi(G,H)$ looks/sounds perfect!

Comment: Isn't that what the wreath product is for?

Comment: @FriedrichKnop How exactly? Do you mean $H^X\rtimes G$ acts on $X$ in such a way as to in particular recover the action of $H$ on $X/G$? Or you mean something entirely different?

Comment: Perhaps the "permutation direct product" would work? It's described in the opening paragraph of a 1982 paper of Bailey, Praeger, Rowley and Speed. On first glance it seems stronger than your set-up because, as I understand it, you aren't specifying exactly what $H$ does to the elements of $X$... But certainly such an action would allow you to recover the set-up you describe. I think!

Comment: @NickGill Although it certainly is a wreath product of sorts, I - sorry for my stupidity - still do not see how exactly to use it. Do you mean something like the action of $H^X\rtimes G$ on $(X/G)\times X$ given by$$(\eta,g)\cdot(\chi,x)=(\eta(x)\cdot\chi,g\cdot x)?$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand the question: I'm suggesting you use a direct product rather than a wreath product. I, and some co-authors used the permutation direct product in this paper -- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.13869.pdf . It's described briefly in the middle of p.4. The explanation isn't as good as the one in the other paper I mentioned, but I give the link in case you can't access the other one.

Comment: I guess my suggestion will work provided the action of $H$ on $X/G$ preserves orbit sizes, i.e. $|\gamma|=|\gamma^h|$ for all $h\in H$ and $\gamma \in X/G$. Is this the case in the situation that you are considering? (If it isn't, then my instinct is that there is no very satisfying answer to the question... But I could be wrong.)

Comment: Well, thinking some more, if your $H$-action *doesn't* preserve orbit sizes, then I guess you could "pad out" sets in $X/G$ in the same orbit of $H$ with dummy elements, and then the underlying set in $X$ corresponding to each such $H$-orbit $\Lambda$ would admit a bijection to a direct product $\Lambda\times \lambda$ (where $\lambda \in \Lambda$) and you could apply the permutation direct product to that? Is that too convoluted though?

Comment: @NickGill Thanks for additional explanations. Could I create confusion with my notation $H^X$? I meant the set of all maps from $X$ to $H$ rather than fixed points (which do not make sense in this context).

Comment: As for your last comment - do you suggest to extend the action to the disjoint union $$\coprod_{\lambda\in X/G,\Lambda\in X/H,\lambda\in\Lambda}\Lambda\times\lambda?$$