# Is the composition of group quotients a group quotient?

Tags: group-actions, quotient-space

I have two sets $X_1$, $X_2$ each with a corresponding group action $G_1$, $G_2$. Linking the two sets is $f:X_1\to X_2$ that maps orbits of $G_1$ into the same point in $X_2$. In other words  $X_1/G_1 \simeq f(X_1)$. Thus, we can think of the group $G_2$ as acting on the orbits $X_1/G_1$, which gives rise to object I'm trying to understand, the quotient $(X_1/G_1)/G_2$. Is this an object commonly studied? What type of structure does it have?

The main question I care about is: Under what conditions there exist a group $H$ acting on $X_1$ s.t. $X_1/H \simeq (X_1/G_1)/G_2$?

An example: $X_1=X_2=\mathbb R^2$. The first group is the 4 reflections along the axis $G_1\simeq C_2\times C_2$. $f$ is just the component wise absolute value, mapping the whole plane into the positive quadrant. The second group $G_2$ is any line subset under addition (the kernel of a linear map $A:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$).

Comment: You should say what $X_i$ is (what kind of structure, preserved by the group), to make your question possibly answerable.

Comment: I am not sure that I understood the question correctly. At any rate, the composition of Galois covers generally is not a Galois cover.

Comment: @YCor I made the question much more specific. $X_i$ is always $\mathbb R^n$ and the functions $h_i$ are either linear or component wise absolute values.

Comment: But what is the structure on $\mathbf{R}^n$? it's viewed as topological space with actions by homeomorphisms?

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ as a manifold. The functions $h_i$ would be embeddings or submersions in the linear case and covering maps if they are the absolute value.

Comment: The absolute value is not a covering map...

Comment: I thought it was. Every point in the image has a discrete fiber and the reflections are the automorphism group of the map. There are singularities so some fibers have different numbers of points, but I don't think that stops it from being a covering map.

Comment: @CarlesGelada: yes, it stops it from being a covering map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Formal_definition

Comment: Ok. I think I understand. At the singularity there isn't an open neighborhood that is mapped homeomorphically. What I'm I working with then? Is there a word for covering maps with singularities?

Comment: I think it would be better to split your question into two. First, given an action of a group $G_1$ on a set $X$ and another action of a group $G_2$ on the orbit set $X/G_1$, what structure is the combination of these two? Second, under what conditions does this structure reduce to an action of a single group $G$ on $X$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე thank you very much. This is a much cleaner way to phrase the question.

Comment: I actually had almost the same question, [A group action on another group action quotient: how to best describe the resulting structure and does it have a name?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/363341/41291)